# Call dll functions with only pointer

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, delphi-xe2, openvr

I am trying to use openVR dll from delphi.
However, this dll got only limited function exported, a lot of function is stay inside interfaces.

since there are some samples for using openVR, so I take a look at  [c version header](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr.h) and a [c# version header](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr_api.cs) to see how they do that.

I do not get quite knowledge from the c header, while in the c# header, I notice they are using [some struct](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr_api.cs#L16)(like interface in delphi) to store the function table, and have [an class](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr_api.cs#L1406) (like implementation class in delphi) for that struct, inside the class there is an create function witch seems like hack the pointer to all these functions.

```
IVRSystem FnTable;
internal CVRSystem(IntPtr pInterface)
{
    FnTable = (IVRSystem)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pInterface, typeof(IVRSystem));
}
```

The `pInterface` pointer is given at a big class which contains a set of the implementation class.

```
public CVRSystem VRSystem()
{
    CheckClear();
    if (m_pVRSystem == null)
    {
        var eError = EVRInitError.None;
        var pInterface = OpenVRInterop.GetGenericInterface(FnTable_Prefix+IVRSystem_Version, ref eError);
        if (pInterface != IntPtr.Zero && eError == EVRInitError.None)
            m_pVRSystem = new CVRSystem(pInterface);
    }
    return m_pVRSystem;
}
```

where `OpenVRInterop.GetGenericInterface` is one of the exported function by dll.

So my problem are :

(1) can delphi did something like what C# does? it seems like he call these functions just by the raw pointer (address? offset?) I searched for delphi deal with dll, only for two ways(static and dynamics) both require function names.

```
function someFunction(a : integer) :integer; stdcall; external ’someDll.dll’;

dllHandle := LoadLibrary(’someDll.dll’);
@someFunction := GetProcAddress(dllHandle,'someFunction');
```

(2) How is the c header did the library load? I did not find related code there.

Comment: One thing: due to the fact that stuff must be marshalled between C# and the DLL, it is always a little harder to translate than a nice plain C header. C and Delphi understand each other very well. So instead of using the C# demo, try the C demo. And yes, it will probably use pointers.

Comment: Copying C# marshalling isn't going to be useful. You need to gain understanding. No short cuts.

Comment: The OpenVR API is using non-COM interfaces based on C++ abstract classes. Delphi does not support consuming C++ classes, it uses a different model for its interface support. The C# code gets around this issue by marshaling plain structs that contain simulated vtable pointers to match the C++ class's memory layouts. C users have to do the same thing when using C++-based COM interfaces. You will have to do something similar in Delphi as well, so translating the C# code instead of the C code makes more sense in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Remy's advice, I think I worked out a solution for that.

I do translate the C# header to delphi and it works fine now.

I will use VRSystem as example.

First, we need some basic enum, const, struct translate.

enum do need a Z4 tag to make the size match c style enum.

```
{$Z4}
ETrackingResult = (
    ETrackingResult_Uninitialized = 1,
    ETrackingResult_Calibrating_InProgress = 100,
    ETrackingResult_Calibrating_OutOfRange = 101,
    ETrackingResult_Running_OK = 200,
    ETrackingResult_Running_OutOfRange = 201
);
```

for struct, record is perfect match.

```
TrackedDevicePose_t = record
    mDeviceToAbsoluteTracking : HmdMatrix34_t;
    vVelocity : HmdVector3_t;
    vAngularVelocity : HmdVector3_t;
    eTrackingResult : ETrackingResult;
    bPoseIsValid : boolean;
    bDeviceIsConnected : boolean;
end;
```

and then we need to declear delegate functions for every function inside the inside the interface like this.

```
_GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize = procedure(var pnWidth : uint32; var pnHeight : uint32); stdcall;
_GetProjectionMatrix = function(eEye : EVREye; fNearZ : single; fFarZ : single; eProjType : EGraphicsAPIConvention) : HmdMatrix44_t; stdcall;
...
_AcknowledgeQuit_UserPrompt = procedure(); stdcall;
```

and a struct to hold them, but this time we need a perfect size match so we need packed record

```
PIVRSystem = ^IVRSystem;
IVRSystem = packed record
    GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize : _GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize;
    GetProjectionMatrix : _GetProjectionMatrix;
    ....
    AcknowledgeQuit_UserPrompt : _AcknowledgeQuit_UserPrompt;
end;
```

and finally a class holds the struct and will init this struct by giving an pointer to it.

```
CVRSystem = class
    FnTable : PIVRSystem;
    Constructor Create(FNPointer : IntPtr);

    procedure GetRecommendedRenderTargetSize(var pnWidth : uint32; var pnHeight : uint32);
    function GetProjectionMatrix(eEye : EVREye; fNearZ : single; fFarZ : single; eProjType : EGraphicsAPIConvention) : HmdMatrix44_t;
    ...
    procedure AcknowledgeQuit_UserPrompt();
end;
```

so now we can use these functions by calling the function inside `CVRSystem` which directly point to the function inside the `FNTable`

By this way, we use a struct as function table,I wonder if there will be a more tricky way to hack with the virtual method tables.